# Bash: how to filter tee output in realtime for ssh command?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, tee

My goal is to make a timestamped log of the commands used in my ssh sessions.

Tee works in realtime as long as the output is not filtered. When I tail -F test.log, the following command appends output in realtime:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh "$@" | tee -a test.log
```

However, when I try to modify tee's output by methods suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205250/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-output-in-bash-to-different-places-with-different-fil), the output is no longer in realtime. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh "$@" | tee >(grep -e '.*\@.*\:.*\$.*' --color=never >> test.log)
```

Strangely, if I substitute the "yes" command instead of the ssh command, the output is filtered properly in realtime.

Realtime processing is important because my script needs to append a current timestamp to each line and remove as much output as possible. Here is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile=~/test.log
desc="sshlog ${@}"
tab="\t"
format_line() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")${tab}${desc}${tab}${line}"
    done
}
echo "[START]" | format_line >> $logfile
ssh "$@" | tee >(grep -e '.*\@.*\:.*\$.*' --color=never | format_line >> $logfile)
echo "[END]" | format_line >> $logfile
```

How can I fix this, and why is the ssh command acting differently with tee than the yes command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is most likely that `grep` is buffering its output — selecting large chunks of input, filtering them, and outputting the result — so it handles the output of `yes` smoothly (because `yes` quickly generates a lot of input for it to filter and output), whereas your `ssh` command probably doesn't generate as much output as quickly.

Many versions of `grep` offer a mechanism to tweak this buffering. Since you're on Linux, you're likely using GNU Grep, which offers a `--line-buffered` flag for this purpose (see [the "Other Options" section of the GNU Grep Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Other-Options.html)), so that the output is buffered just one line at a time:

```
ssh "$@" | tee >(grep -e '.*\@.*\:.*\$.*' --color=never --line-buffered >> test.log)
```

Comment: if you were using awk instead of grep you would use `fflush();`  .  This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098382/bash-how-to-add-timestamp-while-redirecting-stdout-to-file

Comment: @ruakh I've tested your command of tee output redirection

Generally speaking:  'some command' | tee >( 'some filtering' > 'output' )
It works using /bin/bash it works.  But I got syntax errors using it in /bin/sh,
such as: Syntax error: "(" unexpected.

Any suggest?
Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @GrayFox: The process substitution (the `>(...)` feature) here is actually in the question -- I just included it here to show the `--line-buffered` option in context -- so I think it's off-topic for this question to ask how to approximate process substitution in a shell that doesn't support it. Fortunately, you don't need to ask: this question already links to https://stackoverflow.com/q/12205250/978917, which has several answers showing *non*-process-substitution-based approaches.